# HTML Integrated Canvas with JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I limited the script to the canvas part, I solved all JS exceptions, but the scripts do not react when the buttons are triggered. Why does it not draw a line?
I know the randomization of hex code isn't optimal yet, but why does it not do anything but creating 2 buttons?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('resizable');
        if (canvas.getContext){
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        } else {
  alert("Your browser does not support <canvas> elements/HTML5")
}


ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.save();


var i = 0;
var j = 0;


var iData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height); 
for(var i=0; i<iData.data.length; i+=4)
{
    iData.data[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+3]=255;
    }
ctx.putImageData(iData,0,0);
}

function reset()
{
   ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
} 
    </script>




<canvas id="resizable" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px;"></canvas>

<button onclick="draw()">GO</button> 

<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: There are too much problems in your code, that would each need a separate answer (luckily enough, these answers are already in stackoverflow so the search shouldn't be too complicated). First, start by using the developer tools of your browser and try to correct the errors that are logged in your javascript console.

Comment: Yes, I've started with chrome dev console before trying it here. The problem using the search function was that I had no idea what I was actually looking for,

Comment: @hindmost I guess my questions are; is it possible to finish my project the way i've started it. I've used canvas' documentation to create this and merged some jquery to fulfill what I was looking for.

Comment: @runze, yes it's not how you write a for-loop. But before that, that's not how you declare variables, you will have to learn about function scope, canvasContext.createImageData does return an object, if you do call it like that it won't have any effect, ctx.save() is  a method, but you really don't need it, you're not drawing anything, and you should better iterate through the imageData's data and finally, simply setting an id to a script tag won't allow you to call its content as a named function.

Comment: @Kaiido Just saw your reply, I looked through the code again; I hope my last changes covered your hints. Thanks a lot for the fast reply.

Comment: You're still confusing `ctx.save()` with `ctx.stroke()` but it won't work either (well it will draw a rectangle of one random color). The best way is : `var iData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height); for(var i=0; i<iData.data.length; i+=4){iData.data[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);iData.data[i+1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);iData.data[i+2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);iData.data[i+3]=255;}ctx.putImageData(iData,0,0)`

Comment: tried to implement that, solved all exceptions, but does not display anything on trigger

Answer (score 0):

The problem with resizable or setting the size in css is that the canvas will behave as if it were the origin/default size (100x100) and scale the contents. If you're using an image editor this is like changing the image size, where you're trying to change the canvas size.

You need to change the canvas `width` and `height` attributes, not the css width and height properties.

Comment: so is it canvas.style.width? that's what I had found in the documentation but the explanation appearantly didn't help me to decide for the right option.

Comment: updated first version; I managed to solved all js exceptions, but it still doesn't work. Why does it not draw/react when I press the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as expected:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function draw() {
canvas = document.getElementById('resizable');
        if (canvas.getContext){
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        } else {
  alert("Your browser does not support <canvas> elements/HTML5")
}


ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.save();


var i = 0;
var j = 0;


var iData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height); 
for(var i=0; i<iData.data.length; i+=4)
{
    iData.data[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    iData.data[i+3]=255;
    }
ctx.putImageData(iData,0,0);
}

function reset()
{
   ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
} 
    </script>




<canvas id="resizable" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px;"></canvas>

<button onclick="draw()">GO</button> 

<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```